# Why weblogic crash after deploying application with quartz bean

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, quartz-scheduler

I have some simply application which run on weblogic server. Now I want to add new feature: quartz scheduler but when I add this bean in my context:

```
  <bean name="bean1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  </bean>
```

then my weblogic crash. Here is some information from dump file:

```
Error Message: Illegal memory access. [54]
Signal info  : si_signo=11, si_code=1 si_addr=(nil)
Version      : Oracle JRockit(R) R28.1.1-14-139783-1.6.0_22-20101206-0241-linux-ia32
CPU          : Intel Westmere (HT) SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 Core Intel64
Number CPUs  : 3
Tot Phys Mem : 6442450944 (6144 MB)
OS version   : CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
Linux version 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5xen (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Tue Oct 22 13:32:58 EDT 2013 (x86_64)
Hypervisor   : Xen v3.1
Thread System: Linux NPTL
LibC release : 2.5-stable
Java locking : Lazy unlocking enabled (class banning) (transfer banning)
```

without this bean is everything fine. I really dont know why this happens. Please help

I am using weblogic 11g version: 10.3.4.0 and quartz 2.1.3

Comment: I think it's time to call Oracle for that one.  It seems like something bad happened in the JVM.

Comment: Or try running with a regular JDK and not jrockit to see if it still happens